# Custom Grid with Images

Tags: html, css, grid-system

So I have used libraries like Bootstrap3 as I am learning web development, but I want to further my knowledge in web dev by fully understanding and being able to recreate some things that are available in bootstrap.  I'm currently messing around with a custom grid and putting images into it that will remain responsive.  The problem is that I want the images to all be at one height no matter what the size of the images are in my row.  The width for the images is exactly what I thought, but I can't get the height to be the same (or at least cut off any excess images.  This is my [Custom Grid CodePen](https://codepen.io/Kotsenburg/pen/jwoVWw) that I am working on.  I have already googled answers but a lot of answers to questions are using `background-image` properties which I am not using, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

**Edit:**

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <img class="responsiveImage" src="https://source.unsplash.com/M8spMIQcg24">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <img class="responsiveImage" src="https://source.unsplash.com/U--hvQ5MKjY">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <img class="responsiveImage" src="https://source.unsplash.com/F3ePNdQb_Lg">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
}

.responsiveImage {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to have the images fill their respective columns but all have the same height?

You could of course add wrapping divs around the images and make them `height:200px` and `overflow:hidden`. But this would not be responsive.

What you want, if I understood you correctly, cannot be done in CSS without the use of flexbox or javascript. See this codepen which I shamelessly picked from google: https://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/gpard. Or a more in depth look: https://clearleft.com/posts/270

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify the height you want, then set the image width to `auto` to keep it proportionately scaled.

```
.responsiveImage {
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 30%;
}
```